# Replace special characters in multiple columns and calculate yearly pct changes in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working at a dataset as follows:

```
structure(list(date = structure(1:24, .Label = c("2010Y1-01m", 
"2010Y1-02m", "2010Y1-03m", "2010Y1-04m", "2010Y1-05m", "2010Y1-06m", 
"2010Y1-07m", "2010Y1-08m", "2010Y1-09m", "2010Y1-10m", "2010Y1-11m", 
"2010Y1-12m", "2011Y1-01m", "2011Y1-02m", "2011Y1-03m", "2011Y1-04m", 
"2011Y1-05m", "2011Y1-06m", "2011Y1-07m", "2011Y1-08m", "2011Y1-09m", 
"2011Y1-10m", "2011Y1-11m", "2011Y1-12m"), class = "factor"), 
    a = structure(c(1L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
    7L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 21L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L), .Label = c("--", "10159.28", "10295.69", "10580.82", 
    "10995.65", "11245.84", "11327.23", "11621.99", "12046.63", 
    "12139.78", "12848.27", "13398.26", "13962.6", "14559.72", 
    "14982.58", "15518.64", "15949.87", "7363.45", "8237.71", 
    "8830.99", "9309.47", "9316.56", "9795.77"), class = "factor"), 
    b = structure(c(1L, 15L, 22L, 23L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 
    13L, 16L, 1L, 21L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
    20L), .Label = c("--", "1058.18", "1455.6", "1539.01", "1867.07", 
    "2036.92", "2102.23", "2372.84", "2693.96", "2769.65", "2973.04", 
    "3146.88", "3227.23", "3604.71", "365.07", "3678.01", "4043.18", 
    "4438.55", "4860.76", "5360.94", "555.51", "653.19", "980.72"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

I'm trying to calculate `yearly_pct_change` for column `a` and `b`, so firstly, I replace `--` in `a` and `b` with `NA`, then convert `date` column，the code I have used:

```
df[df == "--"] <- NA

df$date <- as.Date(paste0(df$date, '-01'), '%YY1-%mm-%d')

df %>%
  # mutate(date = lubridate::ymd(paste0(date, '-01'))) %>%
  mutate(ratio_a = round((a / lag(a, 12) - 1)*100, 2),
         ratio_b = round((b / lag(b, 12) - 1)*100, 2))
```

In the final result, `ratio_a` and `ratio_b` are all `NA`s.

But with data as belows I manipulated in excel by replacing `--` into `space`, it works:

```
structure(list(date = structure(1:24, .Label = c("2010Y1-01m", 
"2010Y1-02m", "2010Y1-03m", "2010Y1-04m", "2010Y1-05m", "2010Y1-06m", 
"2010Y1-07m", "2010Y1-08m", "2010Y1-09m", "2010Y1-10m", "2010Y1-11m", 
"2010Y1-12m", "2011Y1-01m", "2011Y1-02m", "2011Y1-03m", "2011Y1-04m", 
"2011Y1-05m", "2011Y1-06m", "2011Y1-07m", "2011Y1-08m", "2011Y1-09m", 
"2011Y1-10m", "2011Y1-11m", "2011Y1-12m"), class = "factor"), 
    a = c(NA, 7363.45, 8237.71, 8830.99, 9316.56, 9795.77, 10159.28, 
    10580.82, 10995.65, 11327.23, 11621.99, 12139.78, NA, 9309.47, 
    10295.69, 11245.84, 12046.63, 12848.27, 13398.26, 13962.6, 
    14559.72, 14982.58, 15518.64, 15949.87), b = c(NA, 365.07, 
    653.19, 980.72, 1455.6, 1867.07, 2036.92, 2372.84, 2693.96, 
    2973.04, 3227.23, 3678.01, NA, 555.51, 1058.18, 1539.01, 
    2102.23, 2769.65, 3146.88, 3604.71, 4043.18, 4438.55, 4860.76, 
    5360.94)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Does someone could help me to figure out why my code above give `NA`s for ratio columns? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data has factors, try to convert them to number.

```
library(dplyr)

df[df == "--"] <- NA
df$date <- as.Date(paste0(df$date, '-01'), '%YY1-%mm-%d')
df %>% 
  type.convert() %>%
  mutate(ratio_a = round((a / lag(a, 12) - 1)*100, 2),
         ratio_b = round((b / lag(b, 12) - 1)*100, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks, any ideas how to replace `--` in `a` and `b` with `NA`? Or maybe I post a new question regarding this.

Comment: @ahbon It did get replaced for me `df[df == "--"] <- NA` I have `NA`'s in `a` and `b` in place of `'--'`.